# QGIS3 won't install on mac with python3.6 already installed through Ananconda

Tags: python-3.x, macos, installation

*QGIS* installer keeps telling "QGIS requires Python 3.6." after which it quits installing on *Mac*. However I have python 3.6.4 at least on 4 locations

1) ~/anaconda/bin/python

2) /usr/bin/python3

3) /usr/local/bin/python

4) /usr/local/bin/python3.6 (through a symbolic link).

All these files refer to the same file, when invoking them they all yield:

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Does anyone know where `QGIS3` installer looks for `python 3.6`, so I could set a symbolic link to the `python 3.6` version that is already installed through `Anaconda`?

Thanks, Theo

Answer (score 13):

Ran into this problem myself. Creating a symbolic link to where the installer expects to find python works. I had to find where Homebrew installed Python... (note the version in the path)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I had python 3.6 installed by Anaconda.

Answer (score 5):

I had python 3.7 and QGIS 3.X was looking for python 3.6.

error: "*qgis requires python 3.6*"

to downgrade I tried many things but finally "brew prune" and installing 3.6 directly from python.org worked for me.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-366/

Comment: yup, that worked for me too. The brew switch option didn't work, nor did downgrading miniconda. Only the direct install from the web site worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had to install python 3.6 directly downloaded from www.python.org (ignoring the already installed version by Anaconda). This worked. See remark on http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180315_qgis_3_must_use_python.org_python_3

Comment: Additional note: Python 3.7 doesn't work, it must be a Python 3.6.x release from python.org.

Answer (score 2):

Install via the terminal with

```
conda install -c conda-forge qgis
```

I had the same issue and could only install QGIS with this solution. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274600/77207), the path is in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.x.y_z/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Python 3.6.5 from the main [Python webpage](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/) ignoring the existing ***Anaconda*** version that I use regularly. Then once it is completed I checked my PATH and I had both directory

```
echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/anaconda3/bin:
```

You can check the folder of python using `which python3` and it should give you the Frameworks.

I installed the GDAL and then QGIS without any problems. I run QGIS and it is working, until now :)

**Remember:** you will need to use pip3 to install any missing modules other wise it you will be calling the pip under anaconda.

owslib, PyYaml, psycopg2, jinja2, pygments, numpy, plotly.

```
pip3 install modulename
```